# unable to set higher ulimit value for max open files

Tags: linux, ulimit

On Ubuntu 16.04 AWS system with 32 GB ram and 4 CPU, the following commands fail,

```
root@ip-10-0-0-189:/home/ubuntu# sysctl -w fs.file-max=10000000 **(ten million)**
fs.file-max = 10000000
root@ip-10-0-0-189:/home/ubuntu# ulimit -n 2000000 **(2 million)**
**bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted**
root@ip-10-0-0-189:/home/ubuntu#
```

Is there any upper limit on value that can be set on ulimit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have small investigation and able to change this situation on my Ubuntu 14.04. You should change `fs.nr_open` value in sysctl.conf, e.g. `sysctl -w fs.nr_open=10000000`, after this you could change your limits as you want.

```
root@:~# sysctl -w fs.nr_open=1000000
root@:~# ulimit -n 2000000
root@:~# ulimit -n
2000000
```

More info about this case I found in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127777/how-to-configure-the-process-open-file-limit-of-a-user).